# Accessing localhost and virtual host together

Tags: php, apache, localhost, virtualhost

For the development purpose and Version control trade offs I use Virtual host on apache server. Now I have an installation of MedialWiki on my machine and I want MediaWiki to be accessed by all the users on an office LAN. But, even though I have enabled virtual host, LAN users can not access MediaWiki by my IP address and the folder name, i.e. `http://192.168.1.10/mediawiki`.

Is there any solution to this that i can use both a virtual host and localhost together or any other solutions are acceptable.

Waiting for your help.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you have to setup your router properly.

Comment: This is entirely an Apache configuration issue. Show the content of your `.config` files for each virtual host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having virtual hosts enabled doesn't prevent people from accessing your server by IP, but it means you have to think about which `<VirtualHost>` they see.

If you're using name-based virtual hosting, requests that don't match the name of any configured virtual host will be handled by the *first* virtual host defined in the configuration.  You can define a `VirtualHost>` specifically for that purpose, and put MediaWiki there.

See the paragraph titled "Main host goes away" in the [Apache name-based virtual hosting documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).